# Why can't I connect to any site until I've timed out first?

Tags: windows, networking, windows-10, connection

After a Windows update, I've lost the ability for any program to connect to a site until it's timed out, stopped trying, and then attempted again. Firefox, Edge, IE, Opera, even Command Prompt - Any program that tries to connect to an IP or URL. They will all fail the first time, then I close the tab or program, open it again, and it'll succeed (Which has to be repeated many times for things like CDNs).

Other computers on my network can use the internet without any problems. Booted from a LiveCD, my computer can use the internet no problem. Local HTML files and the like will load instantly. It's seems not a DNS issue, as Command Prompt will find the IP right away (and nslookup works fine), it just fails to connect until I've tried a second time.

These pings were done 3 seconds after each other, and repeatable with any given URL or IP:

[image: pings]

Once I've connected to a site completely, they tend to work fine for a day or two before having to do the recreate tab dance again.

I've tried reinstalling network drivers, uninstalling/reinstalling the updates, resetting the network adapters, resetting my router, flushing the DNS, resetting winsock ipv4 and ipv6, safe mode, messing with windows firewall, sfc /scannow and chkdsk. I'm pretty much out of ideas.

I'd really rather avoid resetting windows as a whole, because reinstalling some programs is impossible now.

Comment: [In-place Upgrade](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html) will keep your applications, but take first an image backup of the system drive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying as much as possible, I changed my DNS from Google's 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 to my ISP's DNS servers, which appears to have solved the issue. Even though the issue was happening with IPs. Maybe something about the Windows Update made my computer start bugging out and DNSlookuping IPs, or somethin'. Solved anyhow.